# angular regex not validating on input box

Tags: angularjs, regex

Why is my regex not being triggered?  The first error message "Please enter the longtitude" is displayed when nothing is entered.  If I entered an obviously wrong value for "longtitude" the error message is not displayed.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <label for="name">Longtitude</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/" ng-model="report.lon" name="lon" id="longtitude" placeholder="Enter the longtitude" required />
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="submitReport.lon.$error" ng-if="submitReport.lon.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">Please enter the longtitude</div>
            <div ng-message="lon">Your longtitude is invalid</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="submitReport.lon.$error.pattern" ng-if="submitReport.lon.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">Please enter the longtitude</div>
            <div ng-message="lon">Your longtitude is invalid</div>
    </div>                                                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/WPjGeylGESDexh7Q6UKJ?p=preview

Also please note your spelling for Longitude is not correct.

**Edit**

The problem in the code is that

`<div ng-message="lon">Your longitude is invalid</div>`

should be

`<div ng-message="pattern">Your longitude is invalid</div>`

Comment: While yours evaluates to true/false it doesn't show the error messages so you're having the same problem.

Comment: Fair call. I didn't include the script library for ngMessages nor include it in the module's array.  I've updated the plunk so it works fully

Comment: How very odd.  So far I can only get the message to show if I do `<div ng-show="submitReport.lon.$valid == false">Your longitude is invalid</div>` there's nothing odd in the controller, just a couple of functions.  The form name is correct too.  I'll think about it for a bit longer before posting any more code.

Comment: Have you included the ngMessages library in the module - angular.module('ngPatternExample', ['ngMessages'])?  It sounds like the library isn't running at all if you have to use ng-show.  That's is core Angular

Comment: And linked to the separate <script> library in the HTML head?

Comment: Yup, its all in the same script and other validation messages work so as far as I can tell I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125388/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-user1532669).